# Что не так с кодом? Python

Tags: python

Дан список чисел. Определите, сколько в этом списке элементов, которые больше двух своих соседей, и выведите количество таких элементов.

Входные данные

Вводится список целых чисел. Все числа списка вводятся на одной строке, разделённые пробелом, и не превосходят по модулю 2^31.

Выходные данные

Выведите ответ на задачу.

Примеры
Ввод 1 5 1 5 1
Вывод 2
Пример моего кода:

```
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
count=0
b=0
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[b]<a[b+1]>a[b+2]:
        count+=1
        b+=1
print(count)
```

Почему он всегда выводит "1", ведь условие находится в цикле?

Comment: пройдись по циклу на листочке с карандашом и посмотри как и когда изменяется b.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=list(map(int,input().split()))
count=0
for i in range(0,len(a)-2):
    if a[i]<a[i+1]>a[i+2]:
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Зачем вам b?